Why would arbitrage lead to price convergence?
I am a beginner to economics.
I am thinking about arbitrage in a simple way, where the price of a good in two markets differs, so you make a profit by buying on the cheaper one and selling on the more expensive one.
It is said that arbitrage leads to a convergence of price in an economy.
How certain is this to happen in real-world scenarios?
I was thinking that in a toy model, you could argue that the main reason the price equalizes is due to supply and demand. Maybe the market that has sold most of a certain good is wants to buy more now, and the market that has more of the good now wants to sell more of it.
In order to incorporate this into a toy model of arbitrage, it would require me to include a function whereby each market calculates what price they are willing to buy/sell each good at.
I guess that makes sense, but the part that feels off to me is that prices are probably determined in a super complex manner in the real world, aren’t they?
If you want to actually estimate how much a price of a currency is going to go up or down when doing arbitrage, do you instead use statistical predictions, since the reality is much more complicated?
Or, is it possible to do arbitrage at a smaller scale where you can assume it won’t affect market prices?

hi julius: one simple way to think about this example is: if the prices of the same asset  in two different markets differs, then the cheaper one will get bought up until the prices are equal. The reason for this is that, if the prices don't converge, then one can buy the cheaper one and sell the more expensive one and enjoy a riskless profit. This is one example of why riskless profits don't exist permanently.
